# ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING on Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, apache, error-handling

I'm getting this error **"ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING"** when browsing between pages. The screen freeze and the error comes up in the inspector **GET (Domain Name)  ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING**

It's a wordpress site. The server has apache installed on it. I'm not sure what the issue could be, but would appreciate the help

Comment: Its a problem in wp-admin , or in the site, or both?

Comment: It happens only when I'm logged in and navigate between the pages. Very strange error.